# Running multiple hiveQL statements in scala code

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I would like to execute a set of hiveQL statements in my spark driver code, something like below

`var res = hiveContext.sql("""use testdb;drop table temp;select ...")`

When i executed this code, it gave me an error saying

```
Error: missing EOF near testdb
```

Can someone point to me where I am going wrong? Is it really possible to execute more than one statement using the approach above?

Further, i tried putting all my statements in a file "test.hql", and used the below code snippet.

```
sqlContext.sql(scala.io.Source.fromFile("mytest.hql").mkString)
```

Still got the same error as above.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

You can put all your queries on file and use this code to execute queries

```
queryFile = "path_of_your_file_queries"
Source.fromFile(queryFile, "utf-8").getLines().foreach(query => sparksql.sql(query))
```